# Is it possible to search for all the occurrences of a property using browser's developer tools?

Tags: debugging, browser

I am debugging my website and I wish I could just search for all the occurrences of property through all the stylesheets.

For example I wish I could find all instances of the property `color: #fff;` and from that quickly browse through the selectors and the correspondent stylesheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. However, this sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). *Why* are you trying to search for all occurrences of a property? Surely you would be wanting to base your styling off the specific **element** that the rule is applied to... If you want to change part of a generic 'theme' though, you'd be better off using something like SASS, LESS or CSS variables.

Comment: Thanks but it is actually much simpler and for a quick fix. At this point I'm just interested in experimenting with colors throughout the website. I wish I could use that scheme to browse through the various elements.

Comment: While you can't search for a property, you can simply add very generic rules with high specificity. If you target **all** elements and override the default colour, would that suffice?

Comment: Well, I further investigated the suggestion on your comment and found out [30 css selectors useful to memorize](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048), but no. I have various links, buttons, elements that turn into a different color on hover. I wouldn't know how to group them in one selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (as far as I am aware) **impossible** to search for a specific selector through the **[F12 Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx)**. Having said that, it is very possible to add generic rules that would **override** existing selectors.

Depending on the *exact* element(s) that you want to modify the styles for, you can use a non-specific CSS selector to target all of them and apply a rule that would override any existing rules. For example, `span` will target *all* `<span>` tags, regardless of ID and class. You can target **any** element with the **[universal (`*`) selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)**.

However, it should be noted that the more 'generic' you are, the less 'specific' you are (which stands to reason). This means that if you have any other rules that are more specific, they will override your generic rules. As such, you'll want to combine a generic rule with the [**`!important` declaration**](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Here's an example of that:

```css
span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px; /* More specific than the * selector */
}

.more {
  color: blue; /* Will override span */
}

* {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: green !important; /* Maximum specificity; override anything */
}
```

```html
<span>One</span>
<span class="more">Two</span>
<div>Three</div>
```

In the above, all `<span>` elements are red. Then `<span class="more">` turns blue, because it has a more specific selector. Although `*` is a **less** specific selector, adding the declaration `!important` to the `color` rule overrides the previous two colours set.

Keep in mind that the above should only be used for *testing*; you will almost never want to apply such a broad selector as `*` for production. Also, avoid using the `!important` declaration outside of testing as well, and instead work with **[CSS specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**.

You can either add the rules directly to your stylesheet temporarily, or preferably add them **client-side** through the F12 Developer Tools. Using the F12 Developer Tools will even showcase when rules are overridden (like in the above example) by placing a line through the middle of them. Rules are displayed from **most specific to least specific**.

The `<span class="more">` from the above example is highlighted here:

[image: Sample]